# Adding own JS on foundation gem - Junior Developer

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

> Hello!
>   I am using **zurb-foundation** 4.0.0 gem on Ruby on Rails project for the first time and I love creating my own Javascript files.
>   I looked for the right answer to solve my problem : How can I add them? And I did not find answer, maybe because I am too junior. By the way, It looks like **it works for a second and then stop working**.
>   I know how Ruby on Rails structure works but not Foundation. For what I found there is this **app.js** where are all the custom js.
>   More specific: Exactly, **where should I place the files? and, Where and what code lines I need to add?**.
>   Thank you and I hope I followed the forum rules correctly.

Comment: I'm bit confused here - what files do you want to create?

Comment: Your question isnt clear. what files are you adding? are you talking about adding js files into rail's javascript directory and set auto compiling etc?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I used to work with Ruby on Rails only, I would like to add the javascript files like I used to do if possible or if there is another way, I would like to know the simplest one for the moment. My idea is, create a .js and add it to my project, llike on rails in app/assets/javascripts